# Why don't we instantiate delegating classes with their delegate objects?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, initialization

I can't imagine a delegating downloader class or CLLLocationManager or tableView be without a delegate. So why do we need create it as an optional?

Why do we do

```
tableview = UITableView()
tableview.delegate = self
tableview.dataSource = self
```

Why isn't the API made so we could just do:

```
tableview = UITableView(delegate: self, dataSource: self)
```

Is this because memory cycles, so we could first `nil` either the delegating class or the delegate class and then the other? Is that the only reason?

Even if that's the case, still isn't it just more convenient to make it insatiable using

```
class tableView{
    var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?
    var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource?

    init(delegate: UITableViewDelegate? = nil, dataSource: UITableViewDataSource?){
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.dataSource = dataSource
    }
}


var tableView = tableView()
```

Comment: What happens when the delegate has a reference back to its delegator?

Comment: Assuming that you already familiar with what is delegation, basicly you don't *always* need to to conform the object delegate; In case of working with -let's say- a table view you would obviously conform to its data source/delegate, but that's not the case for all objects handling behavior/properties.

Comment: What if the `UITableView` is created by a storyboard, not by you?

Comment: @JoshCaswell What happens? You would have a memory cycle when you want to dealloc either of them right?

Comment: That and you would have a chicken-and-egg problem when you tried to create them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requiring a delegate to be declared on instantiation adds no real benefit to the language itself. It's a convenience that you as the developer could easily add, if you really felt the need, but it doesn't belong in UIKit.

But digging deeper, you wouldn't always want to instantiate the tableview with a delegate anyway. What if the delegate doesn't exist yet? Delegates are not always `self`. You may need to build out your tableview with attributes for displaying or implementing at a later point.

You may also want to change the delegate, which for someone reading code, could add a lot of unnecessary obfuscation to debugging. Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
var tableview = UITableView(delegate:self)

var childController = ChildControllerWithTableView()
childController.prepareForSegue() {
    childController.tableview = tableview
    childController.tableview.delegate = childcontroller
}
```

Not only have you changed the delegate, confusing future developers (probably yourself included!) but you also had to (unnecessarily) set the delegate to `self`, simply because `childController` didn't exist yet.

Or what if the delegator is the delegate, as Josh points out?

```
var tableview = UITableView(delegate:tableview)
```

Wait, what? That's not gonna fly!

Still, you can add this to all your projects if you like - if there's a business need (or convenience) reason to do it! It's what makes Swift so awesome:

```
extension UITableView {
    convenience init(delegate: UITableViewDelegate? = nil, dataSource: UITableViewDataSource?){
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.dataSource = dataSource
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is, 10X more you would see folks **forgetting** to set their delegate. So it makes sense to put it inside the initializer

Comment: Then you as the developer are more than welcome to add that convenience method if you feel you need to, but it has no business being in the standard Swift library.

Comment: "What if the delegate doesn't exist yet?" It's optional field and also settable for later.

Comment: I quickly made an edit on my question, you could easily do `var tableview = UITableView()` and later assign it... so again no confusion

Comment: Well... yeah! Do it. Just trying to explain why it'll never find its way into the standard Swift library.

Comment: The moment I finally *got it* was when I figured out that - back in the day - there was "loosely coupled" and "tightly coupled". Delegates kind of fall in between. Consider the *delegate*... you may wish to *only* instantiate something. Use it's functionality. You spoke of a `UITableView`....

Comment: ....How about it's `UITableViewCell`? Maybe all you wish is to grab something from an array *index* that populated it. But what if you wish to grab a link - populated in the cell but *not* through the source array - and do something with it? That's my "quickest" example of where you want a delegate for the cell along with code for the cell (both).

Comment: Also don't forget that delegate has to be `weak` by definition, therefore it has to be an optional. And also it can be an outlet, therefore assigned after initialization.

Comment: Yeah, Honey did call that out - that this is a convenience init, not a requirement.

Comment: FYI, UITableView is in UIKit, not the Swift Standard Library. My work here is done. https://www.xkcd.com/386/  

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are several scenarios where you do **not** need a delegate.

Look at the following screen.

[image]

### Question

How many elements without its delegate can you find?

### Answer

There are 4 UI elements without a delegate:

1. A `UITableView` in the top of the screen
2. The `UITextField` for the Username
3. The `UITextField` for the Password
4. A `UITextView` in the bottom of the screen

Comment: This probably points towards the root of the question, which is that a **true** "delegate" really _should_ be optional. The object should be perfectly able to function without it; the delegate interface is just for customizing behavior. The term may get a bit overloaded across the Cocoa world.

Comment: @JoshCaswell This comment  of yours is the best answer :D. Luca Thank you so much for pointing this out.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you wouldn't say that for the tableView's dataSource would you? That doesn't really qualify as something optional to me. You need `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` implemented for every tableView and for those to work you need your `dataSource` set...

Comment: Absolutely, that's why it's not a delegate. :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell is there any counter argument for not having the datasource  in the `init`?