# Property 'self.delegate' not initialized at super.init call after upgrading to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

After upgrading to Swift 3 I now get this error:

> Property 'self.delegate' not initialized at super.init call

On NSObject Class defined

```
open class NSObject : NSObjectProtocol {
   public init()  
}
```

IQKeyboardReturnKeyHandler class

```
public override init() {
   super.init()    //Error here
}

public init(controller : UIViewController) {
   super.init()    //Error here
   addResponderFromView(controller.view)
}
```

Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that in your class IQKeyboardReturnKeyHandler you have such declaration:

```
weak var delegate: YourDelegateProtocol
```

Since it's neither an optional nor an implicitly unwrapped you have to initialize it **before** calling the initializer of the superclass.

However, using the delegate pattern, it's better to declare your delegate property as an optional:

```
weak var delegate: YourDelegateProtocol?
```

In this case it isn't necessary to set the delegate before calling the initializer of the superclass, so your code will look like this:

```
weak var delegate: YourDelegateProtocol?

public override init() {
    super.init()
    self.delegate = nil
}

public init(controller : UIViewController) {
    super.init()
    self.delegate = controller
    addResponderFromView(controller.view)
}
```

**Important!** When using the delegate pattern, **always** declare your delegate property as **weak** to avoid [reference cycles](https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/swift-retention-cycle-in-closures-and-delegate-836c469ef128?gi=f5d2274e9cc4).

Comment: It's working on public init(controller : UIViewController) method. Still have error in public override init() method

Comment: @Aruldevi I've updated my answer. You can follow the case with the optional delegate.

Comment: @Aruldevi delegates should ALWAYS be optionals. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337259/why-dont-we-instantiate-delegating-classes-with-their-delegate-objects)