# Property 'self.delegate' not initialized at super.init

Tags: ios, swift

The error occur in my program. Please help me how to resolve this error?

> Error occurs : Property 'self.delegate' not initialised at super.init
>   call

```
override init(reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(selectHeaderAction(gestureRecognizer:)))
    }
```

I actually dont know how to resolve this error??

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470511/property-self-delegate-not-initialized-at-super-init-call-after-upgrading-to-s?rq=1) already. But just to iterate it one more time, if your variable is not declared as optional, it has to be not nil after your init function runs, otherwise that causes an error. It's better to declare it optional, like in the post mentioned above.

Update:

As mentioned in the comments, including relevant parts of code. The delegate should be declared like this:

```
weak var delegate: YourDelegateProtocol?
```

The error will go away because an optional variable can be nil, there is no problem with that until you need to unwrap it.

Comment: If a question has been asked and answered before then you can *flag it as a duplicate.*

Comment: Ok. thanks, I'll know next time. This time It's already marked.

Comment: Edited upon your suggestion.